# PostgreSQL 14: Run `psql` as `postgres`, different behaviour on Arch and Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 14.6 with the same database (`mydb`) on two systems.

On Arch Linux, I'm able to use `psql` using both ways:

```
sudo -i -u postgres psql mydb
sudo -i -u postgres psql 'host=localhost user=postgres dbname=mydb'
```

Both commands give me a console `mydb=#`.

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, however, the first variant works:

```
sudo -i -u postgres psql mydb
```

But not the second one:

```
sudo -i -u postgres psql 'host=localhost user=postgres dbname=mydb'
```

Which asks me for the password:

```
Password for user postgres:
```

Does anybody have a hint where this difference could be configured? I don't know where to start my investigation: is it an issue with the DB user or the OS user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is related to the default configuration in `pg_hba.conf`.

On Arch Linux (`/var/lib/postgres/data/pg_hba.conf`):

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

On Ubuntu (`/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf`):

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket                                                               
local   all             postgres                                peer                                                
                                                                                                                    
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD                                              
                                                                                                                    
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only                                                                
local   all             all                                     peer                                                
# IPv4 local connections:                                                                                           
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256                                       
# IPv6 local connections:                                                                                           
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256                                       
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the                                                  
# replication privilege.                                                                                            
local   replication     all                                     peer                                                
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256                                       
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

The key is the option `trust` or `peer`/`scram-sha-256`, respectively, in the last column; the former skips authentication on the side of PostgreSQL.